# I am uploading one file successfully by using following code how can i use the same code upload 3 file. I do not want to use code again again

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

NSString *filenames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"front_img"]; 
        NSString *urlString = @"http://ccccc.com/upfile.php";

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames1\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[filenames1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    /*Sending First Image start here*/
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filenames]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData1]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    /*Sending First Image ends here*/


    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

Comment: Please, please edit your question and fix the formatting.

Comment: Why don't you put all of the data into an array, then use a for loop to upload everything in the array?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa it will slow down the performance so i want to append in a single string and then send it to the server.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878816/afnetworking-form-request-multiple-file-uploads-in-one-request

Comment: Yes, why don't you append to the string in a for loop, then send that single string? Appending to a string should not affect performance.

Comment: Ya i have done this as you say and it is working fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

A typical upload http body will look like:

--BOUNDARY_TEXT

Content-Type/Content-Disposition info key values

Base64 encoded file data ...

--BOUNDARY_TEXT

Content-Type/Content-Disposition info key values

Base64 encode file data.

--BOUNDARY_TEXT

You've done the first one, just continue append files according to the format seperatored by the BOUNDARY.