# How many images can be uploaded to AFNetworking at a single time

Tags: ios, afnetworking, alamofire

I would like to know how many images can be uploaded using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) in a single time (at once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many as you want, if you're using multipart form requests. The first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878816/afnetworking-form-request-multiple-file-uploads-in-one-request) may be helpful to you.